# fill values after condition with NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A', 1],
        ['A', 1],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 2],
        ['B', 0],
        ['A', 0],
        ['A', 1],
        ['B', 1],
        ['B', 0]
    ], columns = ['key', 'val'])
df
```

print:

```
    key val
0   A   1
1   A   1
2   A   1
3   B   2
4   B   0
5   A   0
6   A   1
7   B   1
8   B   0
```

I want to fill the rows after 2 in the val column (in the example all values in the val column from row 3 to 8 are replaced with nan).

I tried this:

```
df['val'] = np.where(df['val'].shift(-1) == 2, np.nan, df['val'])
```

and iterating over rows like this:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    df['val'] = np.where(df['val'].shift(-1) == 2, np.nan, df['val'])
```

but cant get it to fill nan forward.

Comment: Bread and butter example of how to write a pandas question, well done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `boolean indexing` with `cummax` to fill `nan` values:

```
df.loc[df['val'].eq(2).cummax(), 'val'] = np.nan
```

Alternatively you can also use `Series.mask`:

```
df['val'] = df['val'].mask(lambda x: x.eq(2).cummax())
```

---

```
  key  val
0   A  1.0
1   A  1.0
2   A  1.0
3   B  NaN
4   B  NaN
5   A  NaN
6   A  NaN
7   B  NaN
8   B  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
ind = df.loc[df['val']==2].index
df.iloc[ind[0]:,1] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get index by `df.index[df.val.shift(-1).eq(2)].item()` then you can use slicing

```
idx = df.index[df.val.shift(-1).eq(2)].item()
df.iloc[idx:, 1] = np.nan
df
  key  val
0   A  1.0
1   A  1.0
2   A  NaN
3   B  NaN
4   B  NaN
5   A  NaN
6   A  NaN
7   B  NaN
8   B  NaN
```